# Etiquette for improving the quality of your own answer?

Tags: discussion, editing

Let's say that you have a highly ranked accepted answer.  You notice that, while your answer is still valid, you could further improve the answer with an addendum.

Is it better to add the addenda by editing the answer, or by commenting on the answer?

(Keeping in mind that the content of the original answer will remain untouched and is still valid)

Answer (score 2):

The preferred and encouraged approach is to edit rather than comment. Comments are generally considered temporary clarifications rather than actual parts of the answer.

Remember that Stack Exchange's platform logs all edits to a given post so if something was changed, it'd still be visible in the log.

Comment: Fair enough, but what if said answer appears to be the definitive answer to a particular topic (i.e. shows up at the top of a google search)?

Comment: @CurtisBatt all the more reason to put the material in the post. Google doesn't seem to consider comments much when indexing.